# MYSQL result formatting

Tags: php, mysql

Say if we had:

```
tbl `posts`

id | post_type | post_id | post_key | post_value                      | Locale 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | news      | 1       | title    | The climate in Mongolia         | pl_pl
2  | news      | 1       | content  | Mongolia has strange weather... | pl_pl
3  | news      | 1       | date     | 2015-9-24                       | pl_pl
```

In order to get data for a post I would

```
SELECT post_key, post_value 
FROM posts 
WHERE post_id = 1 && post_type = 'news'
AND locale = 'pl_pl'
```

Then loop through the result set and mysqli_fetch_assoc() each row to give me an associative array with field names as the array keys;

```
$row['post_key'] == 'title'; $row['post_value'] == 'The climate in Mongolia';
$row['post_key'] == 'content'; $row['post_value'] == 'Mongolia has strange weather...';
```

What I would like is the actual values of `post_key` to be the array keys, keeping the value as `post_value`. So:

```
$row['title'] == 'The climate in Mongolia'; 
$row['content'] == 'Mongolia has strange weather...';
```

Yes I could format it like this with php and another loop, like:

```
$data = [];

foreach($rows as $r) {
    $data[$r['post_key']] = $r['post_value'];
}
```

But I want to know if there is some mysql magic that could save the additional processing required in PHP?

---

Further info about this app: As Gal rightly pointed out, it seems strange that I wouldn't just use the field names as per the post_key's / conventional table design. But this is a translations table and I am exploring the possibility of having one table to cater for translations of many other content tables, and that I can use for new content types without too much faffing around with creating multiple additional tables and maintaining new fields across them. Reasons that I am not to worried about performance at this stage: 1. being the only developer on this startup project and where decisions are being made on the fly, I believe this will save time and tick all boxes for now. 2, number of entries will be low compared to a couple of years time, where we would have time then to look a solution to any performance issue that arises.

Comment: I don't think PHP has anything like this. You can use array_map or array_walk but best is foreach...

Comment: The structure of your table is whole wrong and would cause performance issues when you will start adding more posts. instead of `post_key` you should have created a new columns for `title`,`content` and `date` as there wont be a post without them,right?

Comment: @Gal I should have explained my app better, this is for a translations table and I am doing this over having multiple, separate other tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a select like this to get all the post_key->post_value in a single row:

```
SELECT
  title,
  MAX(content) AS content,
  MAX(date) AS date
FROM (
  SELECT
    post_type,
    post_id,
    CASE
      WHEN post_key = 'title' THEN
        post_value
    END AS title,
    CASE
      WHEN post_key = 'content' THEN
        post_value
    END AS content,
    CASE
      WHEN post_key = 'date' THEN
        post_value
    END AS date
  FROM
    posts
  WHERE
    post_type = 'news' AND
    post_id = 1
) AS a
GROUP BY
  post_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04684/1

**UPDATE:**

You can do something like i exposed but using the column value as a column name like this questions:

[mysql select dynamic row values as column names, another column as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925445/mysql-select-dynamic-row-values-as-column-names-another-column-as-value)

[MySQL select specific row values as column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977322/mysql-select-specific-row-values-as-column-names)

Then call a procedure like this:

[How to call a MySQL stored procedure from within PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966747/how-to-call-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-within-php-code)

Hope it helps you!

Comment: +1 as this theoretically answers my question, but the whole point in having a table like this is to be versatile and save the need to maintain other tables and field names. So the time here to maintain individual queries specific to the post_type is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

[You could.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422461/mysql-query-combine-rows-with-same-id-and-keep-all-entry-for-that-id-but-as-on) But as Gal stated, it's probably not the most efficient. If you value efficiency, I'd advice to just make meaningful columns.